# Count of prime numbers in random sequence (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a task to find the count of all prime numbers in random generated sequence.
The input is:

```
25 10
```

where 25 is the number `s` which should be < 10^3 and is used for `srand(s)` and the number 10 is N(the length of the sequence) which should be < 10^9. The numbers in the sequence are generated with `rand()%1000`. There are no more than 100 total examples. So here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
         if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Solve(int s, int N)
{
    if (s >= 1000 || s <= 0 || N > 1000000000 || N <= 0)
    {
        cout << "s or N out of bounds!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    int number,
        count = 0,
        i;

    srand(s);

    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        number = rand() % 1000;
        if (isPrime(number))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int s, N;
    int counter = 0;
    while (cin >> s >> N)
    {
        if (++counter == 100)
        {
            cout << "You have reached the maximum examples(100)!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        Solve(s, N);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And when I input `25 10` the answer should be 3 but I got 1. Where is my problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider better primality test. Testing all the numbers from range (0,n) is extremely inefficient.

Comment: This is an odd challenge, given it is implementation defined what `rand` does. Are you sure your `rand` yields the same sequence as the `rand` you compare against?

Comment: Why do you think that the answer should be 3 rather than 1?

Comment: My lecturer gives this example and he said it should be 3 not 1

Comment: Run your program on your lecturer's computer.

Comment: When I run it (cpp.sh/4vqu) i get 2 as the output...

Comment: Your code creates the numbers 61,788,660,168,960,193,515,752,186,312 [for me](http://ideone.com/WF8Ie7). Seven of them are even, one is a multiple of 5, and two of them are prime.

Comment: Ok thank you guys but tell me on the first look of my code do you recognize something wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from input of numbers because i dont put them in array because if we have N = 10^9 the array will be enormous and this will make it slow, so except that i generate a random number in the range [1, N] and check it if that number is prime. Mayve there is the problem. Because my teacher said to use sieve of erathostene?